# nginx redirect, partially working

Tags: nginx, redirect

I am configuring a wordpress site that was working under apache and which I have moved to nginx. The site is for a separate part of a company's activities, i.e., 'trading as'. The parent compamy is KJT Investments Ltd and the trading persona is KJT Aviation.

The website is [KJT Aviation](http://www.kjtaviation.com) and DNS for the parent company points at the ip address of the server serving kjtaviation.com. Both sites are served from the same server & ip address.

Under apache, the redirect was in .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I have created a server file as follows for kjtaviation.com

```
server {
            listen 95.154.237.186:80;
            root /var/www/kjtaviation;
            index index.php ;
            # Make site accessible from http://kjtaviation.com/
            server_name www.kjtaviation.com kjtaviation.com;
            access_log /var/log/nginx/kjtaviation.com-access.log;
            error_log /var/log/nginx/kjtaviation.com-error.log;
            location / {
                            #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                            # PWI 20151112 from here...
                            # https://wordpress.org/support/topic/permalinks-nginx-not-working-help-required
                            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
            }
error_page 404 /404.html;
            location ~ \.php$ {
                            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                            # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
                            # With php5-cgi alone:
                            #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                            # With php5-fpm:
                            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                            fastcgi_index index.php;
                            include fastcgi_params;
            }
location ~ /\.ht {
deny all;
           }
}
```

I have created another server file for the redirect...

```
server {
    listen 80;
    #implemented by default, change if you need different ip or port
    server_name www.kjtinvestments.co.uk kjtinvestments.co.uk ;
    access_log    /var/log/nginx/kjtinvestments.co.uk.access.log;
    error_log    /var/log/nginx/kjtinvestments.co.uk.error.log;
    rewrite_log on;
    return 301 $scheme://www.kjtaviation.com$request_uri;
}
root@srv:/var/www/kjtaviation#
```

These files are linked from sites-available to sites-enabled.

So far so good - the kjtaviation site works and and CURL reports that the redirect for kjtinvestments.co.uk is working...

```
srv# curl -I http://www.kjtinvestments.co.uk/
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.2.1
Date: Fri, 13 Nov 2015 14:27:35 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.45-0+deb7u2
X-Pingback: http://www.kjtaviation.com/xmlrpc.php
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=4dvkba202vic8ajv6l0hdntjd5; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Location: http://www.kjtaviation.com/
```

The problem is, the site does not appear if you go yo http://www.kjtinvestments.co.uk and I don't understand why.

I will be very grateful if someone will point out my error(s)/omission(s) or stupidities ;-).

Comment: Seems to be working for me - redirects me to http://www.kjtaviation.com. What result do you get? Blank page? DNS lookup failed? 404?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I get:-The connection has timed out

The server at kjtinvestments.co.uk is taking too long to respond.

    The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
    If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.
    If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.

Comment: Without being able to replicate the issue myself I'm clutching at straws a bit. :) I would say it sounds like a DNS problem, as if Firefox is contacting the wrong IP address, but then cURL shouldn't have worked if that were the case. Unless your cURL request was done from a different machine? Can you reach kjtaviation.com in Firefox?

Comment: I have just been out for a walk with the dog and I used my mobile via the pub wifi to see the site - and it looks fine. It looks like you are correct it's a DNS problem - my DNS problem behind my firewall. Thanks Doug :).